# Visual Studio / Visual Source Safe / Integrated Security / IIS 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7, integrated-security, visual-sourcesafe-2005

- Using Visual Source Safe with IIS integration (the working dir is the IIS site)
- Visual Studio, pointed to the IIS site would load up the Web project.
- It would be under VSS control (have to check out files, etc).

Recently, we had to switch to Integrated Security for our database connections from the web app.   This means changing the impersonation of the IIS app pool (and anon authentication) to the impersonated account.

Since I did this -- my project loads in Visual Studio, but it acts as if I'm not me, and the files aren't under source control anymore.  I'm going to assume it's something with the pass-through from IIS to the VSS (as if you'll remember you had to add IIS_USERS to the VSS list of users).   Even trying to add the impersonated account didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSS receives many bad rap, but I doubt that it would lose an entire project like that.  You can confirm by installing and running the stand-alone VSS client (hopefully you can determine the VSS server and look for the file called srcsafe.ini and open that using the VSS client).

Comment: VSS didn't lose the project, but it did lose the VSS connection to the IIS and Visual Studio - the integration.

In the end, we ended up just switching to Subversion using TortoiseSVN and for Visual Studio, I use VisualSVN.